# Why am I getting return elements outside of my array I'm for looping on?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, reverse

Given an array I'm trying to return the last even numbers up to a given "number" of items in a new array, it also needs to be returned in original order. I have written the following code:

```
function evenNumbers(array, number) {
   let newarr = [];
   for (let i = array.length - 1; newarr.length < number; i-=1){
      if (i % 2 == 0){
         newarr.push(i);}}
   return newarr.reverse();}
```

So I am trying to start at the back of given array and insert only the even numbers into a new array, up to a length of given "number" length of the new array and return them in the original order. It seems to work fine except that on a few it is returning an array that contains numbers not in the original array I'm looping over. What am I missing?

For example: `evenNumbers([-22, 5, 3, 11, 26, -6, -7, -8, -9, -8, 26], 2)`

returns [8, 10] when it should return [-8, 26]

It correctly returns evens and the number or evens I want but 8 and 10 aren't even in the given array.

I thought I had my for loop set up correctly. It starts at the back of the array `let i = array.length - 1;` it continues while this is true `newarr.length < number;` and iterates one step at a time backwards `i-=1`

My follow-up question is how does my for loop know which array I want to iterate over? I am newer to javascript as I know Python which uses "for i in array" so it knows what array/list you are iterating over. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test the element `array[i]`, not the index, and take it later, if necessary.

Then you need to add a check, if the index is going to be negative and stop the iteration.

And you could use [`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) instead of [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and omit reversing at the end.

```js
function evenNumbers(array, number) {
    let newarr = [];
    for (let i = array.length - 1; newarr.length < number && i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
            newarr.unshift(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return newarr;
}

console.log(evenNumbers([-22, 5, 3, 11, 26, -6, -7, -8, -9, -8, 26], 2));
console.log(evenNumbers([], 2));
```

A shorter approach with a `while` loop and an implicit check.

```js
function evenNumbers(array, number) {
    var newarr = [],
        i = array.length;

    while (i-- && newarr.length < number) {
        if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
            newarr.unshift(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return newarr;
}

console.log(evenNumbers([-22, 5, 3, 11, 26, -6, -7, -8, -9, -8, 26], 2));
console.log(evenNumbers([], 2));
```

Comment: Ahh yes! I should've thought of that! Thank you @Nina Scholz !

Comment: Thank you for the followup info too. You've not only answered my questioned, taught me something and made my code more concise!!

Answer (score 0):

```
function evenNumbers(array, number) {
   let newarr = [];
   for (let i = array.length - 1; newarr.length < number; i--){
      if (array[i] % 2 == 0){
         newarr.push(array[i]);}}
   return newarr.reverse();}

   const az = evenNumbers([-22, 5, 3, 11, 26, -6, -7, -8, -9, -8, 26], 2);


   console.log(az);
```